# WD 3TB HDD showing as only 746 Gb when installed, but okay via media player

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I installed a 3TB hard drive (GPT formatted) in my Astone media player and my PC recognises as 3TB no worries.

I then take it out of the media player any install directly to the motherboard via a SATA cable and viola! It only shows up as 746 Gb.

Refortmatting via MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition or diskpart does not resolve the issue.

PS: I only see 746 Gb, not 2.2 TB as others do and I have a 3 year old motherboard (Gigabyte P55A-UD3R) and BIOS is Award Modular BIOS v6.00PG

Why would these two different results occur?

Comment: This is normally because of how the controller of the media player is configured.  Specific information about the hdd itself would be required.

Comment: Hi Ramhound
it is a WD Green 3 TB HDD.

Comment: Where is it showing up as 746GB? In the BIOS? In some program?

Comment: Hi It is showing up as 746 Gb in My computer, Microsoft Management Consol > Disk management and MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition.  All the usual disk management places.

Comment: Please merge your accounts. http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue, and after using gparted to allocate the unallocated portion of the disk, Windows 7 64 Home Premium showed the full 2.72 TB on my new WD 3TB Black hdd.

After many attempts with WD's tech support, and some online research it seems that any BIOS older than around a year or so will only recognize the 746 GB. However, even though I was able to get Windows to show the full 3TB, I could not use more than the 746GB! So, looked online again and found a suggestion to partition the drive into 2, one less than 2TB or so, and the rest on another.

This seems to allow the full use of all the space, even though the BIOS AND Easeus' Partition Master Pro, still report only the 746GB. Windows disk management shows the full 3TB. It seems this allows one to bypass the 2.19TB limit.

BTW, I ended up using gparted again, to repartition the drive.

Comment: This answer is hard to read. It could be written in 2 sentences. I suggest you read this link http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: For some reason, I cant comment on my own post . . . Thanks for the response and for taking the time explaining the steps you followed.
How do I create two partitions, one of 2.2 Gb, if I can only see 746 Gb?
If I partition the drive into two partitions, say approx 350 Gb each, can I then reformat them - one to 2.2 Gb and the other to 746 Gb?
I will give it a go, but I think disk management will still only see a total of 746 Gb on the partitions
Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Some high capacity drives need drivers. In your case you need to [look here for WD green](http://wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=780).

The drivers should allow the whole storage space to be used.